# Excel VBA - SQL Call - Operation is not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: sql-server, excel, ssms-2014, vba

I have a couple macros to make calls to SSMS 2014 to run a query and return the results in a defined cell in my worksheet.  They work successfully, but when I try to use certain queries with temp tables I get the following error message:

[image: VBA Error Message]

I have researched online and the best answer I can find is to add `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the beginning of my query.  I tried that, and still got the same message.

The piece of code that the `Debug` brings me to is as follows:

`bqr.Range("B6").CopyFromRecordset rst`

The meat and potatoes of my code, along with the variable setups that matter, is as follows:

```
Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String
Dim SOURCE As String
Dim DATABASE As String
Dim QUERY As String
Dim intColIndex As Integer
Dim sDate As String
Dim eDate As String
Dim qt As Worksheet
Dim qtr As Worksheet
Dim bqr As Worksheet
Dim bp As Worksheet

ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & SOURCE & "; Initial Catalog=" & DATABASE & "; Integrated Security=SSPI;"
cnn.Open ConnectionString

cnn.CommandTimeout = 900

StrQuery = QUERY

rst.Open StrQuery, cnn

bqr.Range("B6").CopyFromRecordset rst

For intColIndex = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
    Range("B5").Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = rst.Fields(intColIndex).Name
Next
```

The most confusing part is that the error suggests that my `rst` recordset is closed, even though it is opened just before I use the `CopyFromRecordset`

I've tried adding `DROP TABLE` at the end of my query, the `SET NOCOUNT ON` function at the beginning, and even tested some smaller simple temp tables as tests.

For example, I set my `QUERY` variable to:

```
QUERY = "CREATE TABLE #Test1 (TestID INT, TestValue VARCHAR(20))"
QUERY = QUERY + " INSERT INTO #Test1"
QUERY = QUERY + " VALUES (1, 'Pass'), (2, 'Fail'), (3, 'Try Again')"
QUERY = QUERY + " SELECT * INTO #Test2 FROM #Test1 WHERE TestID = 1"
QUERY = QUERY + " SELECT * FROM #Test2"
```

Then ran the code to extract and past into Excel, and it worked.

Therefore, I am stumped.  Maybe there is a limit to how long the query can be?  Right now it's 180 lines long, so it's pretty big...

Any suggestions are appreciated!

EDIT: Full macro below (less the actual query):

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If TextBox1.Value = "i.e. 20160101" Or TextBox2.Value = "i.e. 20160131" Then

MsgBox "Please fill out all fields before proceeding"

ElseIf Len(TextBox1.Value) <> 8 Or Len(TextBox2.Value) <> 8 Or Not IsNumeric(TextBox1.Value) Or Not IsNumeric(TextBox2.Value) Then

MsgBox "Please use correctly formatted Datekeys (i.e. yyyymmdd)"

Else

Application.DisplayAlerts = False

Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Select

While ActiveSheet.Name <> "[worksheet I want to keep]"

ActiveSheet.Delete

Sheets(ActiveWorkbook.Sheets.Count).Select

Wend

Dim cnn As New ADODB.Connection
Dim rst As New ADODB.Recordset
Dim ConnectionString As String
Dim StrQuery As String
Dim SOURCE As String
Dim DATABASE As String
Dim QUERY As String
Dim intColIndex As Integer
Dim sDate As String
Dim eDate As String
Dim qtr As Worksheet
Dim bqr As Worksheet
Dim bp As Worksheet

Set qtr = Sheets([sheet name])

Sheets.Add after:=qtr
Set bqr = ActiveSheet
bqr.Name = "[sheet name]"
Sheets.Add after:=bqr
Set bp = ActiveSheet
bp.Name = "[sheet name]"

SOURCE = "[server]"
DATABASE = "[database]"
sDate = UserForm1.TextBox1.Value
eDate = UserForm1.TextBox2.Value

QUERY = "[beginning of query]"
QUERY = QUERY + " [more query here]" 'This gets repeated a lot for each additional line in the query'

qtr.Select
Range("B6").Select

While ActiveCell.Value <> ""

QUERY = QUERY + " " + ActiveCell.Value

ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

Wend

QUERY = QUERY + " [more query here]" 'This gets repeated a lot for the remaining lines in the query'



    ConnectionString = "Provider=SQLOLEDB;Data Source=" & SOURCE & "; Initial Catalog=" & DATABASE & "; Integrated Security=SSPI;"

    cnn.Open ConnectionString

    cnn.CommandTimeout = 2000


    StrQuery = QUERY


    rst.Open StrQuery, cnn

    bqr.Range("B6").CopyFromRecordset rst
For intColIndex = 0 To rst.Fields.Count - 1
    Range("B5").Offset(0, intColIndex).Value = rst.Fields(intColIndex).Name
Next

End If

Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: That `QUERY = ` bit near the bottom. Was that ran in `rst.Open`, or did you run that directly in SMSS and paste the values back in excel. The sentence "Then ran the code to extract and past into Excel, and it worked." isn't clear.

Comment: That was run in `rst.Open`, sorry that wasn't clear

Comment: So that worked, but you have some other query that doesn't? Can you share the query that isn't working? Generally a recordset that is closed (or set to Nothing) after attempting to open is the result of the database erroring out for some reason.

Comment: Correct.  The query that doesn't work is 180 lines long though...and editing out the sensitive information would be quite the undertaking.
I will add that the query runs in SSMS successfully, but it does take a little over 20 minutes.  On that note, I also tried changing `cnn.CommandTimeout = 900` to `cnn.CommandTimeout = 2000`, but it still gave the error message

Comment: Is there any error catching happening in this subroutine/function that might be hiding an error from the database? Like a `ON ERROR GOTO...` line that isn't listed here? Sorry for the twenty-questions. This is one of those not-to-sure-troubleshooting type of things.

Comment: No worries, I appreciate you trying.  I'll edit my post to include the full macro less the full query

Comment: Can you try setting the recordset cursor manually and letting us know if you get the same error please. Just enclosing your code in an `If` block would do: `If Not rst.EOF then`.

Comment: Still get the same error

Comment: I think it's your query string then. I seem to recall that I had a similar error when the recordset was empty, but that this error didn't occur when I used a recordset derived from an `ADODB.Command`. In any event, you might be better off parameterising your query, especially one so large. Here's an old post with an example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33005172/sql-query-to-pull-records-of-exception-entry/33007533#33007533

Answer (score 1):

Start your T-SQL query with `set nocount on;`

```
QUERY = "set nocount on;"
QUERY = QUERY & "declare @Test1 table (TestID INT, TestValue VARCHAR(20))"
QUERY = QUERY & " INSERT INTO @Test1"
QUERY = QUERY & " VALUES (1, 'Pass'), (2, 'Fail'), (3, 'Try Again')"
QUERY = QUERY & " SELECT * FROM @Test1 WHERE TestID = 1"
```

Then it should work. The next example will also work and is a bit closer to your example (yet using table variables).

```
set nocount on;
declare @Test1 table (TestID INT, TestValue VARCHAR(20))
declare @Test2 table (TestID INT, TestValue VARCHAR(20))

INSERT INTO @Test1
VALUES (1, 'Pass'), (2, 'Fail'), (3, 'Try Again')

insert into @Test2
select *
from @Test1 WHERE TestID = 1

select * from @Test2
```

Comment: As I stated in the question, I tried that and it still didn't work :(

Comment: If you insist on using temp tables you are right. If you are willing to use table variables instead then it is working as described.

Comment: The basic rule of thumb here is that you can do with Excel only multiple `DML`s. If you wish to issue `DDL`s then each of them has to be sent in a separate query .